# ActiveAndroid Not saving blob type data(Image) in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

This is My model class ...i want to insert image file in db using activeandroid .i converted image file into bytes ... but bytes is not stored in Db ... the field type in Table is Blob

```
import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;

@Table(name = "contact")

public class Contact extends Model {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "PHOTO")
    private String photo;
    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "MEMO")
    private String memo;
    @Column(name = "Image")
    private byte[] _image;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AA supports saving byte arrays and defining custom [type serializer](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Type-serializers) maybe could help you.From performance view, its more useful create a column as a string and get the image from the disk or the web.